Explicit parametrization of a pipe junction?
I am trying to find resources that talk about parametrizing "pipe junctions" such as in the image.

More technically, given $k$ vectors, a radius $r$ and a length $l$. Assume that the "junction" we are parametrizing is defined by the k directions, each opening in the pipe has radius $r$ and each opening is $l$ units way from the point of intersection,
So for example, for a 5-axis joint, we would have 5 vectors, 4 co-planar ones forming an orthogonal cross and one which is orthogonal to the rest.
The parametrization must exist, I will be non-rigorous because I think a visual proof can show it more cleanly and faster.
First we parametrize a sphere, the standard parametrization of the sphere creates a seam along one of the meridians:

Then you can create $k$ holes, by not closing the meridian in subsections:

It seems clear that you can generate $k$ such holes.
And thus there must exist a map from this sphere with holes to the corresponding k-joint.
I am trying to find resources on having an explicit formulation to generate such a shape. Which I believe must exist somewhere as this seems like a very useful tool for CAD, but all resources I have found so far talk about very algorithmic approaches, rather than explicit symbolic formulations for the parametrization.
I was hoping someone could point me to the kind of literature I need.

I don't knot that this can be parametrized, but it looks like you want fillets defined by rolling balls.  See, for instance, https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-8396(92)90016-I .

You should have a look to Dupin's cyclides which are of common use in CAGD for connecting all kinds of tubes, for example here
